# WPF Evenly distribute content Expander.Header in the column DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote a `UserControl` with two levels of `Expander`. `Expander.Header` distributes the nested Grid / StackPanel / Docpanel unevenly. How can I align the elements on the grid in such a structure?

**My view:**
[image: My view]

**My user control xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserInterface.UserStructuresControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserInterface"
             xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MigrationTool.Localization;assembly=MigrationTool.Localization"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource 
            x:Key="TableSource" 
            Source="{Binding Path=TablesCollection}">            
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpandableRow">
            <Expander>
                <Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TableName}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=TableDescription}"></TextBlock>                        
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldCollection}" 
                          CanUserAddRows="False" 
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                            Header="{x:Static res:LocResources.UserFieldsHeader}"
                            Width="*">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Expander>
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>                                                    
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBlock>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>               
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=TableSource}}" 
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                    SortMemberPath="TableName" 
                    CanUserSort="True" 
                    Header="{x:Static res:LocResources.TableNameHeader}" 
                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource ExpandableRow}"
                    Width="*">                    
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**And I also want to ask:** if the cursor enters the open area of ​​the nested Expander while the mouse wheel is scrolling, then the external ScrollBar is no longer active. How can I set the scroll wheel only on an external ScrollBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template replace the stackpanel with a grid that has columns:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <CheckBox></CheckBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

with this:

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"></CheckBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
        </Grid>
```